# Add or calculate weights for meta analysis of single proportions using glmm

Tags: r, metafor

I am conducting a meta-analysis of sensitivities and tried using the metaprop()argument in the meta package to pool single proportions.
Using the logit-link function, the argument will by default choose a GLMM. However there are no weights provided.
Event hough this is the best solution according to literature, the studies which i want to pool vary greatly in samplesize (n=6 to n=568). I think the weighting might be essential in this case and wondered if there is a solution which also offers weights?
In short, i want pooled, weighted subgroub summary estimates which i can show in a forest plot.

my dataset is based on 2x2 table data (true positive, false negative, true negative, false positive), with a proportional outcome (sensitivity or specificity [%]) and the subgroup "exp"(invitro/bacterial)

```
metaprop(E6sens$TP, E6sens$TP + E6sens$FN, comb.fixed=FALSE, comb.random=TRUE, 
         sm="PLOGIT", method.ci="CP", studlab=E6sens$title, byvar=E6sens$exp)
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions

regards,
Julia

Comment: A GLMM will automatically do the weighting - you don't have to specify weights.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt doesnt show up in the created object. But is it possible to include these weights into the forest plot? all effects having the same size does simply look wrong :(